# Bash expression for "x = (x - 1) unless (x - 1 == 0) in which case y"

Tags: bash

I want to decrement a variable 'x', but if decrementing x yields 0, I want to store a sentinel value (say 'hello') into x instead.

I can do this with two expressions:

```
x=$((x - 1))
[[ "$x" -eq "0" ]] && x=hello
```

Is there an elegant one-liner that does this? I've been experimenting with math evaluations and ternary operators but

```
x=1
echo $((x-1 == 0 ? "hello" : x-1))
```

doesn't ever print `hello`, it just prints `0`.

Comment: The ternary operator only works with numbers and interprets any string as `0`.

Comment: Why not use `-1` as the sentinel value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `(( ))` to evaluate if its contents are non-zero, and if they are not, you can conditionally execute a command:

```
$ x=1
$ (( --x )) || x='hello'
$ echo "$x"
hello
```

`(( ))` is evaluated to true (exit status 0) if the expression inside evaluates to non-zero:

- `(( 1 ))` is true
- `(( 0 ))` is false

`(( --x ))` is false if `x` is 1 before evaluating.

If the ternary operator did work with both strings and numbers, this could also be written as

```
(( x = x-1 ? x-1 : 'hello' ))
```

but strings evaluate to 0 in an arithmetic context in Bash.